# Disable the highlighted form when it is in tour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, intro.js

I have a bootstrap tour with a form when the page loads it highlights the form .i want to disable the form when it is highlighted.The user should not able to type the value.
Code:

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.5.0/introjs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.5.0/intro.min.js"></script>

     <div class="card " id="div3" data-step="2" data-intro="Tell us.">    
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item pslist-group-item">
              <div class="row ">
                  <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 ">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 ">
                          <select class="selectpicker" name="b" id="b" required>
                            <option value="1">1 </option>
                              <option value="2" >2</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>                                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 ">
                          <select class="selectpicker" name="ex" id="ex" required>
                            <option value="a">a </option>
                            <option value="b">b</option>
                            <option value="c">c </option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                  </div>
              </div>
            </li>                      
          </ul>
      </div>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () {
          javascript:introJs().start();
      };
  </script>
```

Here is the reference [link](https://introjs.com/) where i took the code.
Can anyone tell me how to do.

Comment: `i want to disable the form when it is highlighted` ==> First you can add `disabled ` in DOM and when clicking the highlighted overlay you can remove the attribute

Comment: @Anuresh can u pls explain how to do

Comment: Did u solve the issue ?

Comment: @Anuresh not yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Firstly add `disabled` with the `select` or `readonly` in `textbox`
>   case

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="b" id="b" required disabled>
    <option value="1">1 </option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
</select>
```

So when page loads with `introJs()` it will be disabled by default.

Now when clicking the *highlight overlay* write Jquery to remove the attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.introjs-overlay', function() {
        $('select').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('input').removeAttr('readonly');
   });
 });
```

Comment: it seems that it is working but for bootstrap selectpicker and jquery revisited tag input  it is not working.I am using the bootstrap select picker and tag input.

Comment: No problem for that add `disabled` for `select` tag

Comment: i have added, but the disable is not removing when we click on body

Comment: Well that's strange , ` $('select').removeAttr('disabled');` ==>this should happen when clicking'  that black overlay

Comment: i have given here is the selectpicker code    <select class="selectpicker" name="in" id="in" required disabled>
  <option value="1">a </option>
  <option value="2">b </option>
</select>

Comment: i have tried with this also  ('.selectpicker').removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167723/discussion-between-anuresh-and-lakshmi-priya).